# Rsyslog incoming messages rotation

Tags: linux, bash, rsyslog, logrotate

I'm using rsyslog on the virtual machine to get via UDP log messages from the multiple remote servers.
I have a lot of messages in /var/log/messages from another servers, the only way to analyze them is column 4 where sender's hostname written.

I want to know if there a way to rotate incoming messages with rsyslog or logrotate to place incoming logs in their files named as server's hostname:

```
server1 --> syslog_server --> /var/log/messages.server1
vpnserver --> syslog_server --> /var/log/messages.vpnserver
...
```

Comment: See: [Storing Messages from a Remote System into a specific File](http://www.rsyslog.com/storing-messages-from-a-remote-system-into-a-specific-file/)

Answer (score 0):

on the rsyslog.conf file of the remote server:

if $hostname contains 'hostname' then {

$template variable_name,"/var/log/message/hostname_%$year%.%$month%.%$day%.log"
local1.* ?variable_name
...
...
..
}

however on the local server it is interesting not to write the logs on the messages file then you have to modify the file rsyslog.conf:

...........;local1.none /var/log/messages